# XMPPFramework - How can I change my profile status?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, user-presence

For changing my logged status I used the following code:

```
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"away"];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

But I am not getting the reference of `[self xmppStream]`. So I changed to the following code:

```
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status"];
    [status setStringValue:@"away"];
    [presence addChild:status];
    NSError *error = nil;

    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream disconnect];
    NSString *myJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDelegate.jid];
    XMPPJID *JID;        
    JID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID];
    NSLog(@"%@",JID);
    [xmppStream setMyJID:JID];
    xmppStream.hostName=@"talk.google.com";

    [xmppStream connect:&error];        
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

Still not getting the changed status. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your status immediately after you're logged in via `goOnline` method as it is called after `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate`.

```
- (void)goOnline
{
    // Initialize XMPPPresence variable
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];

    // Initialize XML element <show/> for specifying your status
    NSXMLElement *show = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"show"];

    // Initialize XML element <status/> for describing your status
    NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status"];

    // If you want your user status to be shown as "Available"
    [show setStringValue:@"chat"];
    [status setStringValue:@"Available"];

    // If you want your user status to be shown as "Busy"
    [show setStringValue:@"dnd"];
    [status setStringValue:@"Busy"];

    // If you want your user status to be shown as "Away"
    [show setStringValue:@"away"];
    [status setStringValue:@"Away"];

    // If you want your user status to be shown as "Off-day"
    [show setStringValue:@"xa"];
    [status setStringValue:@"Off-day"];

    // Add the XML elements to XMPPPresence
    [presence addChild:show];
    [presence addChild:status];

    // Update new presence to server
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
}
```

For more information and an explanation to my code above, visit [Change XMPPPresence to Away/Busy/Invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24773021/2489212.).

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until after you're connected to send stanzas, by listening for `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate` on the delegate.

Also, don't bother to set the to or from JID when broadcasting your presence.